# Floating Footer with 100% height?

Tags: html, css, height, footer

I got the white background (.big-content) to be 100% height by using position:absolute, but now it's making my footer float! How can I fix this? wolvesofys.weebly.com

Here's my CSS: http://wolvesofys.weebly.com/files/main_style.css?1374887463
Here's my HTML: view-source:http://wolvesofys.weebly.com/
I think the wrappers are the issues.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="wrap">
<div class="big-content">
<div class="content">
<div class="container">
<p>Text here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the footer stuff:

```
<footer>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="page_footer">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li><a href="#terms">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
<li>/li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li></li>
<li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<div id="copyright">Content &copy; 2013 FeraLupus.com</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: And you want your footer stays fixed at the bottom?

Comment: @chris yes, it should stick to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

By using height: 100%, all does it tell the class .big-content to fully expand itself to the height of the parent element that it is within.  This does not take into consideration any margin or padding settings that you have (so it could go outside of the parent element or look obscure).

The way absolute positioning works is that it removes it from the "flow" of the page. Your footer isn't technically floating, you are disrupting the flow of it by making the previous element absolute.  Without seeing the actual pages code though, it is difficult to tell you how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is not good to use `absolute` that way, so I delete it.

Instead, I removed the `auto` height from your `.wrapper` class. And added the `fixed` position to your `footer` (in this case, is an acceptable use of that)

Here the live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UYKfJrxbnqYlSiEaitNW?p=preview

You have a problem of width, but thats another issue.